# activate Caching in Webkit .NET Wrapper

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, caching, webkit

I'm using .NET Wrapper in Visual Studio 2008. 
If I start my own Browser, everything runs well (he shows the desired URL). But regarding the fact, that my Browser only shows one window (not several tabs) but actually loads everytime the same webpage, I see a too long start-up time. I suggest that there's no caching active and every time I load my Browser everything is downloaded again, although it should be in the cache.

Thus, I suggest I've to switch on the caching and probably I'm able to locate the cache so that it can be found by the application/own Browser.

Let me know how to do this if there's a way to activate it.

Thanks
Markus G.